# Calculate possible equations that produce a given integer

Tags: vb.net, math, vbscript

I have an integer of x and I am trying to find what equation is possible to produce that integer. This is for the purpose of script obfuscation. I have solved this problem for addition, subtraction, division, square roots, xor, and hex. Most of my answers involve using an inverse equation to solve. I am looking to solve it for:

- Multiplication
- Modulus
- Exponents
- Scientific Notation
- Logarithm
- Any others I did not mention

Here is the Function that I started:

```
Public Function IntegerBreak(PickedInteger)
Randomize()
Dim Switch, Entropy, Result As Integer
Switch = Int(6 * Rnd()) + 1
Entropy = Int(100 * Rnd()) + 1
Select Case Switch
    Case 1
        'addition
        Result = PickedInteger - Entropy
        Return Result & " + " & Entropy & " = " & PickedInteger
    Case 2
        'subtraction
        Result = PickedInteger + Entropy
        Return Result & " - " & Entropy & " = " & PickedInteger
    Case 3
        'division
        Result = PickedInteger * Entropy
        Return Result & " / " & Entropy & " = " & PickedInteger
    Case 4
        'squares
        Result = PickedInteger ^ 2
        Return "Sqr (" & Result & ") = " & PickedInteger
    Case 5
        'xor
        Result = PickedInteger Xor Entropy
        Return Result & " Xor " & Entropy & " = " & PickedInteger
    Case 6
        'hex
        Return "&H" & Conversion.Hex(PickedInteger) & " = " & PickedInteger
End Select
End Function
```

Sample Output:

`-47 + 57 = 10`

`89 - 79 = 10`

`260 / 26 = 10`

`Sqr(100) = 10`

`12 Xor 6 = 10`

`&HA = 10`

**EDIT**: My specific question is how to find out:

`(z*y=x, z%y=x, z^y=x, zLogy=x, or 3.123^10=x)`

What is stopping me from continuing is I do not have a solid background in mathematics, I ran into issues for multiplication because there can be multiple answers on how you calculate an equation:

`(2*6=12, 3*4=12)`

Using the inverse method gave me decimal numbers. I would like any advice for calculating Multiplication, Modulus, Exponents, Scientific Notation, and Logarithms.

Also what is some good information for learning obfuscation?

Answers are acceptable in vb.net or vbscript or mathematical pseudocode.

Pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: So what is your specific question? You seem to be off to a good start. What's stopping you from continuing?

Comment: I may be way wrong here but it looks like you have got hold of the wrong end of the stick with this. Typically in cryptography etc you use a mathematical function that does *not* have a (simple) "inverse equation"

Comment: I fully understand the distinctions between obfuscation and cryptography, obfuscation is a minor annoyance vs cryptography which is a secure method of protecting data.

Comment: Mathematicians are the ones that *really* know what secure encryption methods look like.  You'll find the fruit of their work in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My specific question is how to find out:
>
> ```
> (z*y=x, z%y=x, z^y=x, zLogy=x, or 3.123^10=x)
> ```

For multiplication, divide both sides by `y` and you get:

```
z = x / y
```

Note that even if `x` and `y` are both integers, you may get a fractional `z` (eg. `2 / 7`).

For modulus, note that the result of `z % y` cannot be greater than or equal to `y`. So choosing an arbitrary `y` probably won't be useful, since depending on the value chosen you may not be able to reach `x` at all. You could do it like this:

```
z = x + rnd()*y
```

as long as you choose a `y` value greater than `x`. Note that this definitely only works for integers.

For power, if `x ^ y = z` then:

```
x = z ^ (1/y)
```

(Solving `y ^ x = z` for `x` is completely different.)

Your logarithm example doesn't make a lot of sense because `log` is a unary operation, which means it only operates on one number instead of two. Unless you actually mean "log base y", in which case for `log{y} x = z`:

```
x = y ^ z
```